# How to utilize `FillOutStructureCmd`?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, java, plugin

Basically I'm extending the `CreateStructure.java` plugin so it iterates all functions and tries to automatically create structures on all variables.

It looks something like this:

```
public class CreateStructure extends GhidraScript {

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        FunctionIterator funcs = currentProgram.getFunctionManager().getFunctions(true);
        DecompInterface decomp = setUpDecompiler(currentProgram);
        for (Function fn : funcs) {
            Variable[] allvars = fn.getAllVariables();
            for(Variable var : allvars) {
                /*DecompileResults res = decomp.decompileFunction(fn, 10000, monitor);
                ClangNode nodres = null;
                ClangTokenGroup ccode = res.getCCodeMarkup();
                println("Decompiled " + fn.getName());
                ClangToken tokeres = new ClangToken((ClangNode) var.getVariableStorage().getFirstVarnode());
                */
                //DecompilerLocation loc = new DecompilerLocation(currentProgram, var.getFirstStorageVarnode().getAddress(), fn.getEntryPoint(), res, tokeres,0,0);
                setCurrentLocation(var.getMinAddress());
                FillOutStructureCmd fillCmd =
                        new FillOutStructureCmd(currentProgram, currentLocation, state.getTool());
                fillCmd.applyTo(currentProgram, this.monitor);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private DecompInterface setUpDecompiler(Program program) {
        DecompInterface decompInterface = new DecompInterface();

        // call it to get results
        if (!decompInterface.openProgram(currentProgram)) {
            println("Decompile Error: " + decompInterface.getLastMessage());
            return null;
        }

        DecompileOptions options;
        options = new DecompileOptions();
        OptionsService service = state.getTool().getService(OptionsService.class);
        if (service != null) {
            ToolOptions opt = service.getOptions("Decompiler");
            options.grabFromToolAndProgram(null, opt, program);
        }
        decompInterface.setOptions(options);

        decompInterface.toggleCCode(true);
        decompInterface.toggleSyntaxTree(true);
        decompInterface.setSimplificationStyle("decompile");

        return decompInterface;
    }
}
```

But it only iterates through the functions variables without creating structures - unlike when I position my cursor on a parameter and execute there.

What am I missing?

(You can also see my attempt to retrieve the DecompilerLocation which also doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out something like this does it:

```
public class CreateStructure extends GhidraScript {

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        /*println("" + currentLocation.toString());
        FillOutStructureCmd fillCmd =
                new FillOutStructureCmd(currentProgram, currentLocation, state.getTool());
        fillCmd.applyTo(currentProgram, this.monitor);*/
        FunctionIterator funcs = currentProgram.getFunctionManager().getFunctions(true);
        DecompInterface decomp = setUpDecompiler(currentProgram);
        for (Function fn : funcs) {
            Variable[] allvars = fn.getAllVariables();
            for(Variable var : allvars) {
                /*DecompileResults res = decomp.decompileFunction(fn, 10000, monitor);
                ClangNode nodres = null;
                ClangTokenGroup ccode = res.getCCodeMarkup();
                println("Decompiled " + fn.getName());
                ClangToken tokeres = new ClangToken((ClangNode) var.getVariableStorage().getFirstVarnode());
                */
                DataType dattyp = var.getDataType();
                String datatypstring = dattyp.getDisplayName();
                println(datatypstring = datatypstring.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\*|\\s", ""));
                DecompileResults res = decomp.decompileFunction(fn, 10000, monitor);
                
                ClangTokenGroup tokengrp = res.getCCodeMarkup();
                
                if(tokengrp == null) continue;
                
                ClangToken tokeres = null;
                
                println("searching for " + datatypstring);
                
                mainloop:
                for(ClangNode  token : tokengrp) {
                    if(token instanceof ClangFuncProto) {
                        for(ClangNode  outter : ((ClangFuncProto)token)) {
                            if(outter instanceof ClangVariableDecl)
                            for(ClangNode inner2 : ((ClangVariableDecl)outter)) {
                                if(inner2 instanceof ClangToken) {
                                    if(((ClangToken)inner2).getText().equals(datatypstring)) {
                                        tokeres = (ClangToken)inner2;
                                        println(inner2.getClass().toString());
                                        break mainloop;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        println("" + ((ClangToken)inner2).getText());
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    println(inner2.getClass().toString());
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                }
                if(tokeres == null) continue;
                println("found");
                
                //ClangToken tokeres = new ClangToken(null, datatypstring);
                DecompilerLocation loc = new DecompilerLocation(currentProgram, fn.getEntryPoint(), fn.getEntryPoint(), res, tokeres,1,1);
                println("" + loc);
                FillOutStructureCmd fillCmd =
                        new FillOutStructureCmd(currentProgram, loc, state.getTool());
                fillCmd.applyTo(currentProgram, this.monitor);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private DecompInterface setUpDecompiler(Program program) {
        DecompInterface decompInterface = new DecompInterface();

        // call it to get results
        if (!decompInterface.openProgram(currentProgram)) {
            println("Decompile Error: " + decompInterface.getLastMessage());
            return null;
        }

        DecompileOptions options;
        options = new DecompileOptions();
        OptionsService service = state.getTool().getService(OptionsService.class);
        if (service != null) {
            ToolOptions opt = service.getOptions("Decompiler");
            options.grabFromToolAndProgram(null, opt, program);
        }
        decompInterface.setOptions(options);

        decompInterface.toggleCCode(true);
        decompInterface.toggleSyntaxTree(true);
        decompInterface.setSimplificationStyle("decompile");

        return decompInterface;
    }
}
```

Now I only need to seed out the non structure types because currently it's creating structure for everything.